# execute code snippet after awaitAll finishes

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, kotlin-coroutines

I am uploading an arrayList of images to firebase, and receiving back a list of server side URL's.

```
lifecycleScope.launch {
    val uploadPhoto = UploadPhoto(storage,db)

    localUris.map { uri ->
        async(Dispatchers.IO) {
            when(val result = uploadPhoto.addPostToFireStore(uri)) {
                is Response.Loading -> {
                    //TODO display progress bar
                }
                is Response.Success -> {
                    val remoteUri = result.data!!
                    remoteUris.add(remoteUri)
                }
                is Response.Failure -> {
                    print(result.e)
                    //TODO hide progressbar
                }
            }

        }
        // waiting for all request to finish executing in parallel
    }.awaitAll()
    val rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference

    val newPostKey = rootRef.ref.child("posts").push().key
    val hashPost = hashMapOf(
        "text" to text,
        "id" to newPostKey,
        "images" to remoteUris,
        "user" to getUser()!!.uid,
        "date" to FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
    )
    db.collection("posts").add(hashPost)
        .addOnSuccessListener {
            Log.d(ContentValues.TAG, "post  added")
        }.addOnFailureListener { e ->
            Log.e(ContentValues.TAG, "error adding document")
        }
}
```

this code iterates through the list and uploads each one in parallel, and adds the URL to the local list. However, I need to wait for the list of server side URLs to be populated before accessing the list and using it.

how do I add a single function call after .awaitAll() that must wait for all operations to finish? the only options I see are forEach, and I do not need to do anything more than once, just one upload.

If i try the code immediately after awaitall, it does not execute. If I try it outside the lifecyclescope call, it executes bit does not wait for the threads to all finish.

Comment: It looks correct to me above. How are you verifying that your code below `awaitAll()` is not being executed?

Comment: the code below awaitAll() results in the post being uploaded with empty remoteUris list. If I step through in debug mode then the post is uploaded correctly.

Answer (score 0):

turns out the issue was simply navigating to the next fragment before the task had finished.

Fixed by simply moving the fragment navigation into the onSuccessListener as below. Likely other ways to fix but in this case waiting for the transaction to finish before going to next fragment is desirable.

```
                        }.addOnSuccessListener {
                        parentFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                            .replace(R.id.container, DashboardFragment())
                            .commit()
                    }
```